# Invalid Swift Support-ERROR IOS APP PIBLISHING?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, app-store

I've built a ios application.Everything worked fine in simulators and on my device.I want to publish it to the app store.I made an archive and than I validated it.When I validated it I got an error like : "...description not available."....Than I just tried to submit my app from the xcode organizer.I submitted my archive and everything was fine.Than I got an email from the apple in which it was like : "Invalid Swift Support - The bundle contains an invalid implementation of Swift. The app may have been built or signed with non-compliant or pre-release tools. Visit developer.apple.com for more information.".Could you help me with these problems please?Thank you a lot!

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Check the answer on this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163856/invalid-swift-support-invalid-implementation-of-swift

Comment: I am using the latest xcode version Acey.

Comment: have find a solution ? i have the same problem ....

Answer (score 2):

***Simple Solution :***

Hi, I had same issue and below is the solution :

Just Set the flag EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT to NO in the build setting of Target,Project and everywhere like testTarget as well.

That it !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. 
To fix it and be able to push a build to iTunesConnect I had to do the following:

- Set the flag `EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT` to `YES` in the target settings
- Be sure that Build Phases did not include any other weird targets
- `Logout` all Apple Developper accounts from Xcode and *login with just the one you want to push the app with*.
- Archive and submit the app `with Xcode` and *NOT* with Application Loader.

Why did I need to logout from all of my Apple Developper accounts?

Because Xcode does not know which account to use to upload the binary. Application Loader ask you in the beginning but then, the uploaded build isn't valid...