# Xcode 7.0.1 - Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing.

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, app-store

I try to publish on AppStore an App that contains Swift 2.0 files, but I receive the following email:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "EMO MILANO". To process your delivery, the following issues must be
>   corrected:
>
> Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild
>   your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit
>   it.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the
>   corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

I read the following thread oh stackoverflow ([Invalid Binary Or Invalid Swift Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28011095/invalid-binary-or-invalid-swift-support) [Invalid Swift Support / invalid implementation of swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163856/invalid-swift-support-invalid-implementation-of-swift)) but I don't find any solution.

I Have a project that has multiple target and uses Cocoa pods.

This is a screenshot of the project navigator:

[image]

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To be safe, all components of your app should be built with the same version of Xcode and the Swift compiler to ensure that they work together.

I think you need to do a pod clean and install. I reckon one of your swift pods was created on a old version of Xcode, you updated Xcode and then tried to do a submission to the app store.

Read the apple swift blog about [binary compatibility and frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=)

You will also want to specify that your embedded content contains swift in the build settings:

```
EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT
```

> Enable this setting to indicate that content embedded in a target's product contains Swift code, so that the standard Swift libraries can be included in the product.

Comment: My code is build in swift 2.0, using Xcode 7.0 I have made EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT flag to YES but still facing the same problem.

Comment: @bandejapaisa: Is Tim's solution worked for you?. Because, I am also facing the issue when building via Jenkins. But, It works when building with Xcode. Did you find ways to solve it?

Comment: In our case, a cocoapod was indeed created in a different xcode version , xcode 9.2 vs 9.0.

Answer (score 1):

I just resolved an instance of this problem with Apple support.

The problem turned out to be some junk files were being included in the IPA file from my CI/CD system.  In particular I had a `.gitkeep` file which came from a rsync command, and a `.DS_Store` file which I put there indirectly by poking around with Finder.

The fix was to tighten the rsync command I was using to import some frameworks from Jenkins to exclude `.gitkeep`, `.DS_Store` and any other dot-files.

YMMV.  The support engineer agreed that it was a confusing error message.

Comment: I am also facing the issue when building via Jenkins with the latest SDK Xcode 7.3. Direct build and upload from Xcode works fine. Now, I don't have provision to test your answer, Let me try your solution, once I got it. Is the answer you posted guarantees to be working.