# Unable to submit binary of Cordova/Ionic App to Appstore

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I am having issues submitting app to store. It says "Code object is not signed at all"

This is the third version i've been trying to submit. I successfully submitted previous versions back on 4/15.

Im using a distribution certificate. It build successfully. When i run validate, it passes.

Using **xcode version 6.3.1** , **cordova 4.1.2**. I tried download and install of provision profile and certificate again. I haven't tried recreating certificate, as I already have an app up in store (hidden from sale right now), so wasn't sure if that was such a good idea.

[image]

**Update:** Just noticed during ionic build ios, i get the following error.

```
2015-04-29 17:02:19.779 xcodebuild[22472:16226472]  DeveloperPortal: Using pre-existing current store at URL (file:///Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DeveloperPortal%206.3.1.db).
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I had a similar problem. After verifying I was using the correct provisioning profile, I uninstalled and reinstalled Cordova and that seemed to do the trick.

You could also try uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode. That solved a [different issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163856/invalid-swift-support-invalid-implementation-of-swift#answer-29953576) for me.

Comment: Tried reinstalling both, and that didnt work for me.