# "Invalid Binary" iTunes Connect (Swift 2)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect, swift2

I've uploaded a pure-Swift 2 binary to iTunes Connect, with hopes of distributing via Test Flight.

This should be possible, according to iTunes Connect itself:

[image]

Unfortunately, my binaries are met with an "Invalid Binary" error:

[image]

Obviously, I've tried this a few times. What *hasn't* worked:

- [Setting `Embedded Content Contains Swift Code` to `YES`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27171890/809150)
- Setting `Embedded Content Contains Swift Code` to `NO`
- Setting `Enable Bitcode` to `YES` *(can't find why I tried this)*
- Setting `Enable Bitcode` to `NO`

The error I'm receiving via email is:

[image]

Which seems to suggest that the first screenshot, taken **from iTunes Connect**, is wrong. Have I gone crazy? *(There are those who [think we all have](https://twitter.com/KielO/status/640357892009279488).)*

**Update:** It would appear that some people can upload their iOS 9 betas. After running all of these attempts again, I am not one of those people.

**Update:** This is only happening with one of my apps. The only source or dependency difference between the two is that the *failing app uses the Parse SDK Cocoapod*.

Comment: Lots proposed solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163856/invalid-swift-support-invalid-implementation-of-swift) . First reflex would be to check your Xcode version.

Comment: Also did you try to submit directly from Xcode?

Comment: @NicolasBraun submitted directly from Xcode 7, both the GM and the prior beta.

Comment: I have the same problem. The Xcode version it's the last one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the issue *was* the Parse SDK, which had an available update.

Ran `pod update`, then updated my code to compile against the updates in the SDK.

To address `The files libswiftCoreLocation.dylib don’t match /Payload/My.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib` specifically, I had to do some bundle trickery: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32535087/809150.