# Xcode 7.0.1 - Invalid Swift Support - cocoapods HOW TO FIX?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

Unfortunately upgraded xcode and now trapped in hell.

```
Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.
```

I'm guessing cocoapods is the  culprit as I've successfully uploaded another app to testflight that does not use cocoapods.

How is this fixed?

- I have Embedded Content Contains Swift Code set to Yes
- I've tried a proposed solution of commenting out a few lines in Pods-frameworks.sh suggested here [Invalid Swift Support / invalid implementation of swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163856/invalid-swift-support-invalid-implementation-of-swift?lq=1)

that did not work

My Podfile contents:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 2.0'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
```

Comment: What version of cocoa pods are you using? You can use `pod --version` to figure out.

Comment: I'm using version 0.39.0

Comment: Hmm. What pods do you have?

Comment: I've edited my question to include pods i'm using

Comment: Versions Alamofire (2.0.2) SwiftyJSON (2.3.0)

Comment: Have you updated cocoapods to version 0.39.0? After I updated to it, the problem was gone.

Comment: yes, I'm using version 0.39.0

Comment: @CharlesTruluck thanks very much for you time and suggestions, still struggling with this one...

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Other then below, I honestly don't have any clue- as I have never run into this issue. Sorry!

Comment: @CharlesTruluck np,  just wanted to say thank you

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so on the Apple Developer Forums, I found [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17063) post. Basically, some people found that adding these few things to their .plist files fixed the issue:

```
<key>ApplicationProperties</key>  
<dict>  
  <key>ApplicationPath</key>  
  <string>Applications/<<APP_NAME>>.app</string>  
  <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>  
  <string><<BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER>></string>  
  <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>  
  <string><<YOUR_MARKETING_NUMBER>></string>  
  <key>CFBundleVersion</key>  
  <string><<YOUR_BUILD_NUMBER>></string>  
  <key>SigningIdentity</key>  
  <string>iPhone Distribution: <<CERTIFICATE_NAME>> (<<CERTIFICATE_ID>>)</string>  
</dict>
```

> If you have an old, working archive, you can copy the values from there and simply change the marketing version and the build number.

Then, restarting Xcode.

If this doesn't help, there is more information on [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17063) Developer Form post.

Comment: Strange, right clicking on my .ipa has no "Show package contents" option

Comment: @SamLuther Not strange at all. An .ipa is not a package. It is a zip file. Anyway it isn't clear what you think that has to do with the answer you are commenting on. No one is talking about doing anything to the .ipa.

Comment: @matt ok, it's a package. I'll need to unzip that i suppose. Although that answer seems like a very hacky way to address this issue(if it does in fact), I mean that would get old real quick, yes?

Comment: @matt I should also add that I'm uploading this app via application loader as this is for a client