# How does one (re)install xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, testflight

I made the mistake of upgrading xcode and its been painful.

I'm at my wits end trying to satisfy apples demand of "Rebuilding my app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmitting it."

some details [Xcode 7.0.1 - Invalid Swift Support - cocoapods HOW TO FIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047922/xcode-7-0-1-invalid-swift-support-cocoapods-how-to-fix)

As far as I know I'm using the current public (GM). I'm using version 7.0.1 (7A1001), please someone tell me if thats not the current public (GM).

I've tried just about every "solution" here, the error still persists.

Now I'm down to reinstalling xcode as a last grasp. 
Of course this process is cloaked in mystery, how do you go about "reinstalling" xcode? I've heard that xcode has a "large footprint" so it's just not a matter of trashing the app, is it?

Comment: The re-installation process is quite simple: first you remove the existing version using the special tool and following official instructions, then you install the version you want to have and make sure it is used (again with standard tools). Which part is causing an issue, what have you tried to do ?

Comment: 'special tool", "official instructions" ?

Comment: @zaph yes, you can find more information at one of the numerous questions at SO or by using search engine of the apple developers portal. Please restrain from leaving comments of dubious usefulness in the future.

Comment: Yep, do restrain from leaving comments of dubious usefulness.

Comment: oh yeah, into the octagon... GEEK FIGHT!!!!

Comment: You are missing using the term GM. GM means golden master: the version they believe they _will_ release as final. It is not necessarily the same as the version they _did_ release as final.

Comment: @matt I'm misusing the term? that's apples error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is just a matter of trashing the app and re-installing the older app.

Delete the Xcode, empty the trash. Make sure you get all copies, even ones outside the Applications folder.

Either get a fresh versio from the Apple app store or get an older version from the downloads.

To get the older version 6.4 from: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ You will need to sign-in with your developer id.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any reason to go back to 6.4 You can submit Apps with the current mac app store version 7.0.1 Personally I would try deleting Xcode and reinstalling from the store.

Comment: The OP's question concernes not being able to build with 7.0.1 and a desire to go back to a previous version of Xcode. Updated the question to cover re-installig the current version and an older version.

Comment: I'm not looking to go back to a previous version, just reinstall the current version. a last ditch effort to satisfy the error, since the error says "Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.

Comment: and to clarify, I can build just fine. apple wont accept the build

Comment: I suggest you add that to the question.